# How to Update Aptana Studio to the latest?

Tags: aptana, aptana3, updates

I have Aptana 3.1.1 installed and want to update it to 3.1.3, the latest version. How could i do that?

I have tried the "Check for Updates" under "Help" menu, and it said "No updates were found". I guess that a update site needs to be added, is it?

Hope I don't have to download the latest version to update Aptana...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the update sites list is empty. To add a list, just import the list in the .xml file provided by Aaron K [here](http://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2791-available-software-sites-list-is-empty-on-aptana3).

Answer (score 2):

Please try the suggestions [here](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Errors+While+Updating), in particular the steps under **No updates were found** section.

Answer (score 1):

Said in offical is http://update.aptana.com/update/studio/3.4 But there is nothing.

One of this is works for me. but the version is toooo old.

- http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/update/
- http://download.aptana.com/studio3-rcp/plugin/update/

So found [this](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Changing+the+Update+Type)

**Aptana Studio Beta Updates:**
http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/plugin/update/beta/
**Aptana Studio Nightly Updates:** 
http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/plugin/update/nightly/

Now, I use the beta version. :-)