# How do I update aptana studio to version 3.5?

Tags: aptana

I am using aptana studio v 3.4.2.201308081805 on windows 7, I know that v 3.5 is available because I was prompted to update to 3.5 on a different computer.

I have not received the update prompt on my macbook air or on my work computer. Does anyone know how to force aptana to update to v 3.5?

Comment: Have you tried Help > Check for updates?

Comment: yes that is the first thing I tried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aptana has removed version 3.5 due to several bugs.
Current stable version is 3.4.2
You can check here [Aptana download](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download)

Comment: 3.5 was a real dog; I felt a huge relief after reverting back to 3.4.2 and I'm not going to rush to update even when they re-release 3.5

Comment: Aptana Studio seems to be half dead, I switched editor

Answer (score 0):

Check out the other Stack Overflow question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182618/how-to-update-aptana-studio-to-the-latest). It's also about updating Aptana Studio. Basically, in your case, Aptana may not have the update sites list configured yet. You'll need to import the XML file containing these addresses (many people have had to deal with this, as show in the support thread [on Aptana Studio's support site](http://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2791-available-software-sites-list-is-empty-on-aptana3) about adding update sites to Aptana. Also, check out [this](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Errors+While+Updating) page on the Appcelerator wiki about common issues with updating.